# How can I debug why eclipse won't start?

Tags: eclipse, weblogic, permgen

I've been having trouble getting a weblogic server to run in eclipse, which have resulted in me not being able to open eclipse ni my current workspace at all. It is not my first attempt to work with weblogic servers in eclipse, and I do not know why it suddenly decided to stop working. I have had multiple errors, which all seem to be related to an abnormal high memory consumption.

One of my last errors, before eclipse quit on me for good, was an out of memory exception, on PermGenSpace. I set variables to 1024m, but it still complained it wasn't enough. After a lot of restarts, Eclipse suddenly wouldn't open my current workspace. I have tried others, and they work fine, but with my current one, the splash/loading screen disappears after about 10% of the loading bar is complete, and nothing happens at all. Except the fact that eclipse.exe shows up in the running processes tab on Windows task list. It does not show in the running programs list.

My attempts to start weblogic servers had the exact same symptoms. They showed in the process list, but did not respond when I tried to open the console in my browser.

Both eclipse and the weblogic tasks (shown as java.exe) has had over 400.000KB of memory consumption each, which I find very high.

I do not expect anyone to be able to find a complete solution here, but I am absolutely stuck. I cannot access any of my previous error messages. I have no experience debugging an error like this. Does anyone have any idea on how to find the error in a case like this?

*My Weblogic version is 10.3.2, which is a company standard for now.
My Eclipse version is:
Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
Version: Kepler Service Release 2
Build id: 20140224-0627*

Comment: Try starting up to a new empty workspace; If you dont get to select workspace at startup use the argument "-data <path to ws>"
If you still get issues, look at the log in <workspace>/.metadata/.log

Comment: Well, if I understand you correctly, you want me to start up a new empty work space. This works, as I stated that only the one workspace was giving me grief. I do get to select workspace on startup, so I take it that "-data <path to ws>" is not relevant then? I still have the same issue both when starting the workspace with Eclipse, or trying to switch from another workspace after startup. My <workspace>/.metadata/ does not contain any .log...?

Comment: ...sorry, yes it does! it's just shown in the folder as an unnamed text file. @Fredrik, this means that you have actually answered my question completely. I still need to figure out what is wrong, but now I will be able to write a more qualified question, if I'm not able to solve it just from the error messages. You should write up an answer, and I'll give you that green chevron-thingy. Tack så mycket!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the comment as an answer since it provided some help.

Try starting up to a new empty workspace; If you dont get to select workspace at startup use the argument "-data " If you still get issues, look at the log in /.metadata/.log